# Difficult expected value problem

Tags: probability

It is a variation on a balls in a bucket problem but is slightly different.

There are $m^2$ balls and $m$ buckets.

The $m^2$ balls consist of $m$ types, each has a fixed number on it.

Ie there are $m$ balls with a 1, m balls with a $2$ ,,...  $m$balls with a $m$.

At random we draw balls, and randomly choose a bucket.

If the bucket does not contain a ball of the same type, we place the ball inside.

If the bucket already contains a ball of that type, we put the ball in a garbage bag.

What is the expected number of balls in the garbage bag?

What I thought is maybe it would be equivalent to m times the expected number of balls in the garbage of a certain color.

If that was true (I'm not sure if it is) then the problem could be reduced to that.

But I really am not so sure the best way to solve it.

Comment: Can I assume we will draw balls until all $m^2$ balls have been drawn?

Comment: You may as well concentrate on the $m$ balls with a particular number and multiply the result by $m$

Comment: @MarkFischler Yes we can draw until we have none left

Comment: For each individual type of ball, the number of balls in the garbage is $m$ minus the number of bins that have that type of ball in them, which I think is related to the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: well, yes, there is no reason why - as for expected number - one color should be preferred respect the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a particular bucket and the $m$ balls with a particular number.  The probability that bucket never receives a ball with that number is $\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^m$

So the expected total number of buckets which never receive a ball with that number is $m\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^m$.  That is then equal to the expected number of balls with that number put in the garbage, since they did not go into any bucket

So the total expected number of balls put in the garbage is $m^2\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^m$

which for large $m$ is about $m^2 e^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, apparently it is true that with high probability no bucket contains more then $m(1-(1-1/m)^{m})+2\sqrt{mlogm}$ balls, how could one see that?

Comment: It is harder.  The number of balls in each bucket is binomially distributed with parameters $m$ and $(1-(1-1/m)^{m})$ so the mean is obvious. And there are $m$ buckets, which are almost independent of each other for large $m$.  You might try using [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality)

Comment: So, for $m=2$, we have an expected number of $m^2\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^m=1$ ball rejected. Making  a table of possible dispositions I get instead $4/3$: can you check for that as well ? what are the events that you consider equiprobable?

Comment: For $m=2$, the first ball of each number/colour happily goes into a bucket, while the second may go to the other bucket or may go to garbage, each with probability $\frac12$.  There are two second balls so the expected number going to garbage is $\frac12+\frac12=1$

Comment: @Henry Actually I tried to just use markov and it seem to work. is that ok?